# Grails: Using two databases (one created using domain class, other is an existing DB)

Tags: grails

I recently finished an application using just standard grails way (GORM-domain classes, etc.), but the company is asking me to to include an existing DB from an open source project. Both are just using mySQL DB, which is good, but I'm not sure how to approach this. I've seen some posts regarding grails connecting to multiple DB.

I guess my question is: Is it possible to connect to two databases: one mapped to domain classes and the other not? My primary reason to do this is to keep all the code in one project and reuse code without gutting the project and making a plugin.

Thanks for any insight.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. It is possible - http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/single.html#multipleDatasources

Whether you map the other database to your domain classes or use it through a service layer is up to your design.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the answer. I was also able to find a tool that helps generate the domain class from an existing DB. The tool is called [GRAG (Grails Application Generator)](http://grag.sourceforge.net/index.html) which although is not perfect, it is a bit of a help getting me started faster.

I hope this helps others as well.